# Winforms. How to grab Checkbox values from form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an winform app. There are 5 checkbox's. I need grab their values into array.

Example:

CheckBox's 1-3 are disabled, 4-5 enabled.

In output I want to have an array like this - [False, False, False, True, True].

How can I do this? There's my code I'll tried before (I'll used a list for it, and, yeah, I know, I checked only Checked. But I dont find any method of CheckBox to check their False value):

```
List<bool> properties = new List<bool>();

foreach (CheckBox checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
        properties.Add(checkBox.Checked);
    }
}
```

And yeah, I will convert List to an Array after

Comment: `checkBox.Checked` will be either `true` or `false`. there's no need for the `if`

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Select(b => b.Checked).ToArray()`;

Comment: " I dont find any method of CheckBox to check their False value" as mention by Daniel: this i the property that shows you whether it is true or false

Comment: "n output I want to have an array like this - [False, False, False, True, True]." then you should not skip all the false values! remove the if condition and collect all values

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-checkbox-checked

Comment: @Jodrell, how can I access this array after?

Comment: Searching through controls can be slow.  I usually make my own list : CheckBox[] checkboxes = {checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5};

Comment: are you sure you want it in an array? because you cannot distinguish them afterwards. Is the order irrelevant for you?

Comment: I need this for function after. I need to grab all checkbox values, in the order in which they are located. After convert this bool values to int values, and use this 1, 0 values to math formula

Comment: "in the order in which they are located." how can you be sure that `OfType<CheckBox>()` will yield you this exact order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete your **if condition** so every foreach loop can check each checkbox's checked property and add it to your list. (I tried it and works fine)

```
List<bool> properties = new List<bool>();
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
  { 
     properties.Add(checkBox.Checked); 
  }
```